# Ueberauth plug fails to assign auth and failure to conn

Tags: phoenix-framework, ueberauth

I'm utilizing [Ueberauth](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth) in [a library](https://github.com/britton-jb/sentinel/tree/v2) I'm building to simplify the addition of authentication in Phoenix.

I've setup an [example repo](https://github.com/britton-jb/test_sentinel_example) and you can see the code at in the [v2 branch](https://github.com/britton-jb/sentinel/tree/v2)

I’m attempting to implement the Ueberauth Identity strategy right now. It appears that although I’ve added the Ueberauth plug to the controller, the `ueberauth_failure` and `ueberauth_auth` are not being set in the conn’s `assigns`.  Instead, `conn.assigns` is `%{}`.

I’m expecting that with this example curl request:

`curl -i -X POST localhost:4000/identity/callback -d '{"user": {"email": "test@example.com", "password": "password"}}'`

at least one of those (`ueberauth_failure` or `ueberauth_auth`) will be set?

Ueberauth is configured here: `https://github.com/britton-jb/test_sentinel_example/blob/master/config/config.exs#L58`

The controller implementing the strategy is `https://github.com/britton-jb/sentinel/blob/v2/lib/sentinel/controllers/json/session_controller.ex`

The controller and route are exposed in `https://github.com/britton-jb/test_sentinel_example/blob/master/web/router.ex#L26`

by this macro: `https://github.com/britton-jb/sentinel/blob/v2/lib/sentinel.ex#L50`

Comment: Spoke with @hassox on the Elixir slack and he may found the likely culprit. Will update with answer following testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@hassox](https://github.com/hassox) suggested the correct solution, ueberauth identity's plug must be routed to `/auth/identity/` and `/auth/identity/callback`, as soon as I changed the routing to reflect this everything worked.

Comment: While it is true that the **default** path is `/auth`, it can be customised in the config (alteast in the newer versions of ueberauth) by setting `base_path: "/identity"`